# Using valid wildcard SSL certificate to generate a new certificate for a subdomain

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, truststore

We have purchased a valid wildcard SSL certificate from Entrust.

Let's say it is a wildcard certificate that covers `*.ourcompany.com`

I understand we can use this certificate directly on our web services.

Since, it'll be a lot of servers, we wanted to lock down a little bit the wildcard certificate.

Can we use this wildcard certificate to sign separate set of certificates for subdomains like `service1.ourcompany.com`, `service2.ourcompany.com`, etc. ? (without involving Entrust for each of those subdomains/ subservices).

Pros:

- If one of those services gets compromised, it'll be limited to that service only ;
- We don't have to reach out to Entrust for each of the subdomains (as there could be a lot of them) - also in terms of cost ..

In other words, I'm thinking if it's possible to treat a wildcard ssl cert as an "authority" to validate ssl certs in subdomains. (be part of SSL Certificate Chain)

Thank you.

Comment: Any server cert (wildcard or not) cannot issue other certs. Dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787452/issuing-ssl-certificates-myself-for-subdomains-of-a-domain-i-have-an-ssl-cert-fo but not programming so not really ontopic; better on https://security.stackexchange.com/q/18188/ https://security.stackexchange.com/q/47267/ or https://serverfault.com/q/274852/ . If you have no money LetsEncrypt.org is free, and now supports wildcard (but you do need to run software that interacts with them).

Comment: As dave_thompson_085 said, this assumption: "In other words, I'm thinking if it's possible to treat a wildcard ssl cert as an "authority" " is just wrong. An end certificate is just an end certificate, it "certifies" something (a host, a list of hosts, a wildcard, an IP address, etc.) and that is all. If you want certificates that "validates" other certificates you need to be a CA or subCA. Anyone can technically set up a CA locally, except of course that noone else will trust your CA by default so the certificates created will trigger warnings/errors.

Comment: that makes sense. thank you both